# How do I remove an artifact from a sharp edge?

Tags: modeling

I'm working on a sword with some deformations and i want it to be shaded smooth when exporting it.

[image]

But it has an artifact that im not able to get rid of no matter what i try (bevel, triangulation, connecting to nearest vertex, etc).

[image]
[image]

I tried to recreate it in a new file, and it does have the same issue.

Any help to remove the artifact is welcome!

**Edit:**

I have removed some unnecessary topology and tried to decrease quads and tris as much as possible but the problem still persists.

File:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, the topology is not good, you have a big ngons and what you see are the inner triangles of this ngon, you need to correct the topology, please share your file or show a reference image of your object so that we propose a solution

Comment: @moonboots I have made an edit to the post with the new wip. The reference is just a plain sword with a little chipping. I have minimalized the topology and tried decreasing quads and tris but the problem still persists. How may I be able to fix this?

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: I have made changes to the question as requested.
@moonboots I have added the file in the post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Auto Smooth option, it will prevent the smoothing to happen between faces that are above the desired angle, here between the mirrored faces:

[image]

An alternative would be to simply create this kind of topology with bevels:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I have tried autosmooth but I want the model to be exported in smooth-shaded; since autosmooth and flat shaded makes the sharp edges choppy/pixelated in Substance painter bake.

Comment: so how do you plan to use the Mark Sharp? It is supposed to work with the Auto Smooth. I've edited my answer, at one point I guess you can't avoid bevels

Comment: In general I don't see how sharp edges created by autosmooth would be an issue for any ok quality realtime 3D software - although I haven't used Painter at all. Realtime renderers will usually split meshes on those edges where the shading needs to be sharp. Are you doing some normal mapped stuff with this, and baking textures from highpolys? Did you try having UV-seams/islands where you have sharp edges? It would be interesting to see what kind of artifacts you get in baking (you didn't mention which maps you are baking either). And you didn't mention baking in your question - only in comment.

Comment: Looks like beveling is the way to go. I was trying to keep the poly count to a minimum but i guess this will have to be an exception.

And yes, I am using a high poly model for baking normals onto the low poly model. I will also try splitting the UVs at the sharp edge to see if it works.